# Cual es el error en mi PHP?

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

```
    <?php
 extract($_POST);
    if ($action == "upload") {
        //cargamos el archivo al servidor con el mismo nombre
        //solo le agregue el sufijo bak_ 
        $archivo = $_FILES['excel']['name'];
        $tipo = $_FILES['excel']['type'];
        $destino = "bak_" . $archivo;
        if (copy($_FILES['excel']['tmp_name'], $destino)){
            echo "Archivo Cargado Con Éxito"."<br>";
        }
        else{
            echo "Error Al Cargar el Archivo";
        }


    if (file_exists("bak_" . $archivo)) {
          /** Clases necesarias */
            require_once('Classes/PHPExcel.php');
            require_once('Classes/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel2007.php');

          // Cargando la hoja de cálculo
            $objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007();
            $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("bak_" . $archivo);
            $objFecha = new PHPExcel_Shared_Date();

           $conexion=mysql_connect("localhost","root","mysql")  or die("Problemas en la conexion");
            mysql_select_db("tef",$conexion) or die("Problemas en la seleccion de la base de datos");

          // Asignar hoja de excel activa
            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);


         // Llenamos el arreglo con los datos  del archivo xlsx
            for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
                $_DATOS_EXCEL[$i]['numero_proveedor'] = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B' . $i)->getCalculatedValue();
                $_DATOS_EXCEL[$i]['nombre_proveedor'] = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('C' . $i)->getCalculatedValue();
                $_DATOS_EXCEL[$i]['monto_pago'] = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('D' . $i)->getCalculatedValue();
            }

        }
        //si por algo no cargo el archivo bak_ 
        else {
            echo "Necesitas primero importar el archivo";
        }
        $errores = 0;
        //recorremos el arreglo multidimensional 
        //para ir recuperando los datos obtenidos
        //del excel e ir insertandolos en la BD
        foreach ($_DATOS_EXCEL as $campo => $valor) {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO tef.archivo VALUES (NULL,'";
            foreach ($valor as $campo2 => $valor2) {
                $campo2 == "direccion" ? $sql.= $valor2 . "');" : $sql.= $valor2 . "','";
            }
            echo $sql;
            $result = mysql_query($sql);
            if (!$result) {
                echo "Error al insertar registro " . $campo;
                $errores+=1;
            }
        }
        echo "<strong><center>ARCHIVO IMPORTADO CON EXITO, EN TOTAL $campo REGISTROS Y $errores ERRORES</center></strong>";
        //una vez terminado el proceso borramos el archivo que esta en el servidor el bak_
        unlink($destino);
    }



?>
```

Cuento con este codigo el cual pido que Elija un archivo Excel y al subirlo guarde los datos en mi BD. llamada "tef"  en la tabla "archivo"

pero al subir el archivo me marca este error

> Usted tiene un error en su sintaxis SQL; revise el manual que
>   corresponde a su versión del servidor MySQL para la sintaxis correcta
>   para usar cerca de '' en la línea 1

Comment: saludos karina y bienvenida, te recomiendo que tanto en esta pregunta como en futuras, seas específica en el título; pues como estaba de "cual es mi error?" es muy amplia y no da idea clara de lo que preguntas

Comment: asi mismo te comento que veo error en esta línea  $sql = "INSERT INTO tef.archivo VALUES (NULL,'"; pues no estas cerrando el paréntesis final

Comment: El parentesis lo cierra dentro del for.  Que te aparece cuando haces `echo $sql`?

Comment: Esta mal como construye el query.. seguro! si hace un foreach y hay mas de un registro cierra el parentesis mil veces... con echo $sql vamos a poder ver el query, pero esta mal de seguro

Comment: Lo que pasa es que en la parte de arriba hay mas codigo, no esta mal cerrado... quise poner la parte que empieza a generar error ya que mi codigo tengo costumbre antes de preguntar y pedir ayuda pues de probarlo por partes, me resulta mas facil detectar que parte del codigo genera errores. :)

Comment: ¿En la parte de arriba hay más código?  Pues precisamente el mensaje de error dice que hay error en la línea 1, o sea, precisamente en la parte de arriba. Ya como crítica constructiva, esa forma de construir un `INSERT` dentro de un `for` hace daño a la vista. Resulta difícil dilucidar tu código. Cuando codifiques no lo hagas sólo para ti, codifica pensando que debes escribir con tal claridad que otros lean el código y lo entiendan. Y... si tienes PHP 7, el código no funcionará tampoco, debido a que la extensión `mysql_*` que estás usando fue sacada del núcleo de PHP 7.